# Query for filtering database

Tags: c#

```
DateTime fromDate = dateTimePicker1.Value, toDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DatePurchased <='" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";

using (OleDbConnection conn2 = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query2, conn2))
    {
        command.Connection = conn2;
        conn2.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0:000000}", reader.GetInt32(0)), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphics.DrawString(reader.GetString(1), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX+90, startY + offset);
            graphics.DrawString(reader.GetString(2), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 250, startY + offset);
            graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(reader.GetDouble(3)), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 500, startY + offset);

            startY += 35;
        }
    }
}
```

I am geting an error here:

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

error is

> "OleDbException was unhandled : Data type mismatch in criteria expression. "

I dont know what to do, my data in the database is in Date/Time. Please Help

Comment: Put a `breakpoint` in line `string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DatePurchased <='" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";` and see what is `query2` ?

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to put a breakpoint. can you teach me how?

Comment: check the date format... what about "fromDate" and "toDate" be in YYYY-MM-DD instead of ToShortDateString()

Comment: Make sure you use the same format defined on SQL Server. On a side note, is a bad practice having SQL queries within the code and the way used here is an open door to SQL injection.

Comment: i check my database and "fromDate" and "toDate" its all in MM-DD-YYYY format

Comment: do you have any suggestion on what kind of code should i use?

Comment: Try this `string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased >= " + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + " AND DatePurchased <=" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "";`

Comment: Would you try string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND DatePurchased <='" + toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";

Comment: @Damith i tried that it works for the error issue but when i tried to print it there is nothing

Answer (score 1):

Your ToShortDateString() is not a sql compatible string:

```
fromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

will give you a sql compatible date string.

```
string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+ "' AND DatePurchased <='" + toDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+ "'";
```

However it would be better to use paramerized query.

Comment: how can i use paramerized query?

Comment: for paramerized query see this -> http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/231217/Parameters-SqlCommand-vs-OledbCommand-and-OdbcComm

Answer (score 0):

If that fixed your error try changing your query as

```
string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased between " + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + " AND " + toDate.ToShortDateString() + " "
```

If it is not working please check whether you have data between these two date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string query2 = "select * from Sales where DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND DatePurchased <='" + toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

it worked for me before